# Navigation drawer just following one instruction

Tags: android

I am using a navigation drawer and want it to do different activities for different cases. I am using the switch method to implement the activities. I have implemented 3 switch cases but however, it keeps doing the case 3 instead of case 2. Here is my code that i am using:

```
    PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName("Discover");
    PrimaryDrawerItem item2 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName("Rank Table");
    PrimaryDrawerItem item3 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName("Log out");

    //create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` result object
    Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .addDrawerItems(
    item1, item2, item3

    )
    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
    switch(position){
    case 1: break;
    case 2: startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RankT.class));
    case 3: firebaseAuth.signOut();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    return true;
    })
    .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add **break;** at the end of each **switch** case.

```
switch(position){
            case 1: break;
            case 2: startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RankT.class));
            break;
            case 3: firebaseAuth.signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Ohhh damnnn, Thank you very much.